# How to find out the server's seed if I do not have access to /seed?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I want to find out server's I play in seed to find a nice place to live with creative but the owner never comes online.

Comment: Ask someone who does

Comment: It is simple!!.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find a Minecraft SMP server seed based on known locations](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/95387/find-a-minecraft-smp-server-seed-based-on-known-locations)

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is ask a moderator or administrator to do /seed and tell the seed to you. Most of the time, I'd say that they would tell you the seed, unless it's a survival world, then giving you the seed would give an advantage over everyone else who doesn't.

Comment: They may have legitimate reasons not to though, so don't be offended if they don't. Some admins don't want people recreating the same world locally to explore in creative as it gives an advantage over everyone else on the server.

Comment: @JonK if it's a creative server, most likely they will give them the seed, if it's survival with a *Minecraft* generated world, then no. (Unless it's generated by a plugin)

Answer (score -4):

If you have MINECRAFT pocket edition/pe 1.0.0 the seed is in settings in the game section under the word (world) .