# How would I find the Seed of a MC world without /seed?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

My friends won't tell me because they say I will use it to cheat. I just want the location of the villages.

Comment: So… People who know you well would say that you will use this knowledge to cheat and they don't want you to do that. And you still ask, probably with the intention of cheating against their will?

Comment: @FabianRöling "It's not cheating unless you get caught."

Comment: Try the Seedcracker mod. I'm haven't used it myself but it apparently can be used to get the seed of a Minecraft server

Comment: @OKprogrammer I hope you're not serious with this. Nobody ever says that and actually means it. At most, it's a very weak excuse for "I know that this isn't allowed, but I don't care because I'm selfish". But usually it's meant as a joke.

Comment: @FabianRöling I’m joking. That would be a ridiculous excuse otherwise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find a Minecraft SMP server seed based on known locations](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/95387/find-a-minecraft-smp-server-seed-based-on-known-locations)